# Serializing object to json produce double quotes

Tags: json, wcf, serialization

I have a http invokable wcf service method;

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "/CheckHMAC/{hMac}")]
public string CheckId(string Id)
{
    Result result = new Result() { OTP = 1, IsSuccessful = false, CustomerId = "" };
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
}
```

This method produces an output like;

> "{\"IsSuccessful\":false,\"OTP\":1,\"CustomerId\":\"\"}"

The client which uses this method complains this format since it is not valid, i ve tested it with another client and yes it seems not valid. Until now, i have never had a problem like this, the output should be easily deserialized, why json object wrapped with double quotes? How can i get a valid json string?

> {"IsSuccessful":false,"OTP":1,"CustomerId":""}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it seems i missed this [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25559255/2289430) despite a long search. What is wrong here is the method signature: *string*;

> ..the API controller will serialize the string as a JavaScript string
>   literal—which will cause the string to be wrapped in double quotes and
>   cause any other special characters inside the string to escaped with a
>   backslash.

So, just returning the object itself, makes json data valid for the client.

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "/CheckHMAC/{hMac}")]
public Result CheckId(string Id)
        {
            Result result = new Result() { OTP = 1, IsSuccessful = false, CustomerId = "" };
            return result;
        }
```