# Strange behavior in serialized datatable with newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, serialization, datatable, json.net

I have a very simple datatable which I serialize into JSON using Newtonsoft

```
DataTable dt = DBHelper.GetDataTable(value.Sql);
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.None);
return json;
```

This is the result

"[{\"IdUsuario\":\"37\",\"IdEmpresa\":\"3\",\"Usuario\":\"koala\",\"NombreUsuario\":\"\",\"IdTercero\":\"715\",\"nit\":\"71790599\",\"Bloqueado\":\"0\",\"Descripcion\":\"\",\"IdDependencia\":\"\",\"IdBodega\":\"5\"}]"

I don´t know why i have extra "\" inside the field names, this only happens in this project (WebApi). If i do the same thing from a windows forms test application i have "normal" json.

Comment: Almost certainly because you are double-serializing your JSON as described in [JSON.NET Parser *seems* to be double serializing my objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25559179/3744182).

Comment: That was exactly the case, returning directly a datatable made the serialization. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your string as JSON-String:

```
string jsonConverted = new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```