# JSON string encoded twice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, json.net, javascriptserializer

My Web API (code that generates JSON) is generating the following JSON string. It seems, if I am not wrong, that it has been encoded twice:

```
"\"[{\\\"SportID\\\":1,\\\"SportName\\\":\"Tennis\\\"},{\"SportID\\\":2,\\\"SportName\\\":\\\"Footbal\\\"},{\"SportID\\\":3,\"SportName\":\\\"Swimming\\\"}]\""
```

Web API code:

```
public string JSONTest()
{
    List<Sport> sports = new List<Sport>();
    sports.Add(new Sport() { SportID = 1, SportName = "Tennis" });
    sports.Add(new Sport() { SportID = 2, SportName = "Footbal" });
    sports.Add(new Sport() { SportID = 3, SportName = "Swimming" });

    try
    {      
      return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sports);        
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }            
}
```

`Sport` class:

```
public class Sport { public int SportID { get; set; } public string SportName { get; set; } }
```

Screenshot of getting JSON:

[image: Screenshot of getting JSON.]

The following line gives me an error, I think because of twice encoding:

```
var JavaScriptSerializerResult = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize< List<Sport>>(jsonResponse);
```

I get the same error if try with this:

```
  var jsonConvertResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Sport>>(jsonResponse);
```

How can I fix my Web API to not encode twice, or if that is not the problem, how can I decode this JSON?

Comment: Did you copy that from Visual Studio's locals/auto window or hover-over pop-up? If so, one of the escapes is added by VS. Try copying it from Text Visualizer (the search icon at the right-side of the variable inside autos/locals windows.)

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [JSON.NET Parser *seems* to be double serializing my objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25559179/3744182).  Please provide a [mcve] showing how the JSON is generated to be sure.

Comment: @dbc - Let me share screenshot

Comment: @dbc - I just updated question. you can see more details in it

Comment: Share `Sport()` class as well.

Comment: The answer you accepted doesn't solve the underlying problem of double serialization. It's better to fix the serialization than to hack the deserialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should try `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to deserialize the JSON:

```
public class Sport
{
    // Dummy "Sport" class as it was not mentioned by OP.
    public int SportID { get; set; }
    public string SportName { get; set; }
}
```

I get serialized JSON as:

[image]

Deserialized it:

```
string json = JSONTest();
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Sport>>(json);
```

Output:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

As per OP's shared JSON (which is being received from server), encoding can be removed by using:

```
private string RemoveEncoding(string encodedJson)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(encodedJson);
    sb.Replace("\\", string.Empty);
    sb.Replace("\"[", "[");
    sb.Replace("]\"", "]");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Deserialize it by:

```
string js = "\"[{\\\"SportID\\\":1,\\\"SportName\\\":\"Tennis\\\"},{\"SportID\\\":2,\\\"SportName\\\":\\\"Footbal\\\"},{\"SportID\\\":3,\"SportName\":\\\"Swimming\\\"}]\"";

string res = RemoveEncoding(js);
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Sport>>(res);
```

Comment: I already tried with JsonConvert.DeserializeObject method and got same error. The issue is, my jsonResponse string is encoded twice, I don't know why. Due to encoded twice, it gives error. If twice encoding issue can be fixed then issue will be resolved

Comment: @CuteSparrow Can you share `Sport()` class? because if I serialize this class it is not encoded twice.

Comment: public class Sport
{
    public int SportID { get; set; }
    public string SportName { get; set; }
}

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq Query Concept:

```
  public string JSONTest()
    { List<Sport> sports = new List<Sport>();
                    sports.Add(new Sport() { SportID = 1, SportName = "Tennis" });
    sports.Add(new Sport() { SportID = 2, SportName = "Footbal" });
    sports.Add(new Sport() { SportID = 3, SportName = "Swimming" });
                    var result_sports = (from row in sports
                                           group row by new { row.SportID , row.SportName} into hdr
                                           select new Sport()
                                           {
                                               SportID  = hdr.Key.SportID ,
                                               SportName  = hdr.Key.SportName ,

                                           }).ToList();
                    string jsondata = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result_sports);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter sample for json.net library.
Here, entity is my serializable C# object. I use JsonConvert along with some formatting and specify to ignore reference looping to prevent circular referencing.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (entity, Formatting.Indented, 
           new JsonSerializerSettings {ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

***Summary***: Your return object is being serialized twice. Remove your hand-rolled serialization code and return objects from your web services - not JSON strings.

---

Your JSON is indeed being serialized 'twice'. Look closely at this screenshot and we see escaped quote marks:

[image]

Your list properly serialized should produce a JSON string something like this:

> [{"SportID":1,"SportName":"Tennis"},{"SportID":2,"SportName":"Footbal"},{"SportID":3,"SportName":"Swimming"}]

But we have something more like this:

> "[{\"SportID\":1,\"SportName\":\"Tennis\"},{\"SportID\":2,\"SportName\":\"Footbal\"},{\"SportID\":3,\"SportName\":\"Swimming\"}]"

I can replicate this (code below) and it means that your JSON string has itself been fed through a serializer.

**This is almost certainly due to you manually serializing your `List<Sport>`. You don't need to do that.** Web API serializes for you - hence the second run through a serializer.

Change the return type of your Web API function if necessary, and then instead of writing:

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sports);
```

just do

```
return sports;
```

Web API will take care of the serialization and you will no longer have the bothersome quotes and escape characters.

---

Code dump I tested with:

```
void Main()
{
    string json = JSONTest();
    Console.WriteLine(json);
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Sport>>(json);

    string jsonX2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json);
    Console.WriteLine(jsonX2);
    obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Sport>>(jsonX2); // exception
}

public string JSONTest()
{
    List<Sport> sports = new List<Sport>();
    sports.Add(new Sport() { SportID = 1, SportName = "Tennis" });
    sports.Add(new Sport() { SportID = 2, SportName = "Footbal" });
    sports.Add(new Sport() { SportID = 3, SportName = "Swimming" });

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sports);
}

public class Sport
{
    public int SportID { get; set; }
    public string SportName { get; set; }
}
```