# Newtonsoft JsonConvert.SerializeObject double quoting everything

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I cannot seem to find any other hint of others having this issue, but when I run

```
Dim jsonstring As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(faxtosend)
```

My Json string has everything in double quotes, for example

```
"{""Faxto"":""12345678"",""From"":""87654321"",""Highquality"":false,""Documents"":{""Filename"":""test.pdf"",""FileContents"":""[base64 encoded file]""}}"
```

As you could imagine this is breaking the API I am trying to send the data to. I cannot see any reason for this to be happening. Does anyone have any idea what could be happening here. If I remove the additional quotes the JSON is valid, but I cannot figure out why they are being added in the first place.

Comment: You can patch them using String.Replace, because the code looks right.

Comment: That looks like something afterwards is escaping the string -- the double double quotes is how you escape quotes in a string.  How are you displaying the JSON output?

Comment: Could you provide a desired json output example? I can't figure out what exactly your problme is; double quotes vs double double quotes.

Comment: The above output I got from watching the output of jsonstring. I am wanting to send the output to the GoFax API [found here](https://restful-api.gofax.com.au/swagger/ui/index#!/SendFaxesV1/SendFaxesV1_Send)

Comment: We need to see a [mcve], but I will hazard a guess that you are double-serializing your JSON, e.g. as shown in [JSON.NET Parser *seems* to be double serializing my objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25559179/3744182).  Or perhaps you're serializing your JSON then posting it using an API such as [`PostAsJsonAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944521(v=vs.118).aspx) which serializes it again.  But without a full example I cannot say for sure.

Comment: I feel a little silly now. The issue wasn't the double quotes (while it is still a little weird) The actual issue is that documents is supposed to be an array (so should be surrounded by [ and ]) Thanks all for the help.