# ReadAsStringAsync escapes JSON twice

Tags: c#, json, json.net, task

**Question Background:**

I am receiving a JSON string response from a `HttpResponseMessage` object via the `Task` `ReadAsStringAsync` method, as shown:

```
 string jsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

This gives me the following escaped JSON:

```
"\"{\\\"A\\\":\\\"B\\\"}\""
```

**The Question:**

I believe that this is being escaped twice which mean I am trying to map this JSON to a C# POCO I am having via Newtonsoft to convert it to a string type, then to my desired object type, as shown:

```
  var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result));
```

**Is there a way to stop this double escaping so I do not have to deserialize the JSON twice?**

Comment: Where do you see it being escaped twice? Are you using a Watch, highlighting over the variable when debugging, or writing to console/file? And what is the error you get when you call `DeserializeObject<T>`?

Comment: From where are you getting your json? Did you check your input with another tool, e.g. Postman?

Comment: I suspect that the double encoding it just the ide being nice to you in the debugger preview. Scribble that text into c:/temp/1.txt and have a look, I bet it isn't really double encoded :)

Comment: You are probably inspecting the string by clicking on the magnifying glass which displays it as escaped twice.

Comment: `ReadAsStringAsync` (and related functions) don't do *any* escaping. If unexpected escaping *is* happening (heed the other comments), you need to look elsewhere.

Comment: Possibly there is an error on the server side along the lines of [JSON.NET Parser *seems* to be double serializing my objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25559179/3744182).