# Json Deserialization is not working with Flurl

Tags: c#, json, rest, javascriptserializer, flurl

I try to consume an json APIwith Flurl from a website and I'm getting parse errors or conversion errors. I'm not sure what is my problem since is the first time I deal with json files. I utilize the following online [tool](https://www.site24x7.com/tools/json-to-csharp.html) to create a C# object out of the json file. But when I try to get a response with Flurl I get the following errors.

> *System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Flurl.Http.FlurlParsingException: Response could not be deserialized
>   to JSON: GET  --->
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException:  Error converting value
>   "{"Group":[{"name":"Senior","id":1},{"name":"Age","id":1}],"Area":[{"AreaID":58,"Description":"Years
>   2018-19","Week":1150,"taken":true,"LDate":null","Label":"RED"}]*
>
> *Path '', line 1, position 4814377. ---> System.ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[JsonTest.SeatTest].*

This is the chunk of code that fails:

```
var response = await url.WithHeaders(new
    User_Agent = ConstantData.UserAgent,
    Accept = Accept,
    Referer = Referer})
    ..GetJsonAsync<List<SeatTest>>()
    .Result;
```

But now if I use the following:

```
var response = await url.WithHeaders(new
    User_Agent = ConstantData.UserAgent,
    Accept = Accept,
    Referer = Referer})
    .GetStringAsync()
    .Result;
```

I get (which I think is normal, not sure) the following string when I do a quick watch or hover over the response variable.

> "\"{\\"Group\\":[{\\"name\\":\\"Senior\\",\\"id\\":1},{\\"name\\":\\"Age\\",\\"id\\":1}],\\"Area\\":[{\\"AreaID\\":58,\\"Description\\":\\"Years
>   2018-19\\",\\"Week\\":1150,\\"taken\\":true,\\"LDate\\":null",\\"Label\\":\\"RED\\"}]

If I apply the following:

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SeatTest>(response);
```

it will also throw the exception that I already post.

### OR

If I skip the above line and do the following:

```
var jSerial = new JavaScriptSerializer();
jSerial.MaxJsonLength = 50000000;
string jsonStr = jSerial.Deserialize<string>(response); 
var data = jSerial.Deserialize<SeatTest>(jsonStr);
```

My class objects appear null. But I don't get any errors or exceptions.

The that Flurl code that I'm using looks like follow, or at least the one I want to utilize:

```
 var response = url.WithHeaders(new
                {
                    User_Agent = ConstantData.UserAgent,
                    Accept = Accept,
                    Referer = Referer
                })
                    .GetJsonAsync<List<SeatTest>>()
                    .Result;
```

And my object model looks like:

```
public class SeatTest
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="Group")]
        public List<Group> groups { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Area")]
        public List<Group> areas { get; set; }
     }

 [Serializable]
    public class Group
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }

    }

 [Serializable]
 public class Area
    {
        public int AreaID{ get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Week { get; set; }
        public bool Taken { get; set; }
        public DateTime LDate { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; }
    }
```

I expect an object that is filled with the data that comes from the API, but instead I get exceptions:

> *System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Flurl.Http.FlurlParsingException: Response could not be deserialized
>   to JSON: GET  --->
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException:  Error converting value
>   "{"Group":[{"name":"Senior","id":1},{"name":"Age","id":1}],"Area":[{"AreaID":58,"Description":"Years
>   2018-19","Week":1150,"taken":true,"LDate":null","Label":"RED"}]*
>
> *Path '', line 1, position 4814377. ---> System.ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[JsonTest.SeatTest].*

### EDIT

```
var jSerial = new JavaScriptSerializer();
jSerial.MaxJsonLength = 50000000;
string jsonStr = jSerial.Deserialize<string>(response); 
/*First pass: Here I already got the info that I need, how I map it to my class?, since I would like to use Flurl GetAsync() and map it to my object and not a string */
/*Above line response val:  "\{\\\"Group\\\":[{\\\"name\\\":\\\"Senior\\\",\\\"id\\\":1},{\\\"name\\\":\\\"Age\\\",\\\"id\\\":2}],\\\"Area\\\":[{\\\"AreaID\\\":58,\\\"Description\\\":\\\"Season 2018-2019\\\",\\\"Week\\\":1150,\\\"taken\\\":true,\\\"LDate\\\":\\\"2019-07-07T00:00:00\\\",\\\"Label\\\":\\\"RED\\\"}]} */
/*Above line jsonStr val: null*/

var data = jSerial.Deserialize<SeatTest>(jsonStr);
/*Above line jsonStr val same as raw in postman:  "\{\"Group\":[{\"name\":\"Senior\",\"id\":1},{\"name\":\"Age\",\"id\":2}],\"Area\":[{\"AreaID\":58,\"Description\":\"Season 2018-2019\",\"Week\":1150,\"taken\":true,\"LDate\":\"2019-07-07T00:00:00\",\"Label\":\"RED\"}]} */
/* data value after above line: Group: null, Area: null*/
```

#### Raw Postman Json

```
{
   \"Group\": [
        {
            \"name\": \"Senior\",
            \"id\": 1
        },
        {
            \"name\": \"Adult\",
            \"id\": 2
        }
    ],
    \"Area\": [
        {
            \"AreaID\": 58,
            \"Description\": \"Area 2018-2019\",            
            \"Week\": 1150,
            \"taken\": true,
            \"LDate\": \"2019-07-07T00:00:00\",
            \"Label\": \"RED\"
        },
        {
            \"SeasonID\": 57,
            \"Description\": \"Area 51\",           
            \"Week\": 1,
            \"taken\": true,
            \"LDate\": \"2019-07-015T00:00:00\",
            \"Label\": \"GREEN\"
        }]
}
```

#### Json also how JsonStr (first pass) looks like in Quick watch

```
{
   "Group": [
        {
            "name": "Senior",
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "Adult",
            "id": 2
        }
    ],
    "Area": [
        {
            "AreaID": 58,
            "Description": "Area 2018-2019",            
            "Week": 1150,
            "taken": true,
            "LDate": "2019-07-07T00:00:00",
            "Label": "RED"
        },
        {
            "SeasonID": 57,
            "Description": "Area 51",           
            "Week": 1,
            "taken": true,
            "LDate": "2019-07-015T00:00:00",
            "Label": "GREEN"
        }]
}
```

Comment: Could you post the "clean" JSON of the response? This should be as easy as hitting the endpoint in a browser or Postman and copying the response body. Aside from being easier to look at, it would help ensure the extra quotes/escape characters are being added by the debugger and are not in the actual response.

Comment: The JSON in your question looks to have been some escaping added by Visual Studio, but if not, it was double-serialized on the server side along the lines of [JSON.NET Parser *seems* to be double serializing my objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25559179/3744182).  Can you please [edit] your question and confirm what the RAW response JSON looks like, without any escaping?  If it was double-serialized the best solution is to fix that on the sever side.

Comment: The response string that I have post should have \\\ instead of \\. I try to edit it and for some reason its the same. If write it to a file it will appear with only one \, postman also show the string with one \. The response is 354,505 lines long if I beautify the returned Json. The example json that I post is short because Is just a subset of the entire thing.

Comment: For null date values I have declare my LDate property as Datetime? in my class and assign today DateTime as default value, also I change it to string, but both modification didn't contribute to a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the link @dbc, but sadly I don't have access to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the error message:

> Path '', line 1, position 4814377. ---> System.ArgumentException:
>   Could not cast or convert from System.String to
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[JsonTest.SeatTest].

This is telling you that somewhere in the JSON response (at the 4,814,377th character to be exact), there's a string where in array is expected. It appears that you're expecting both `"Group"` and `"Area"` properties to be arrays in the JSON, but somewhere deep down in the response at least one of them is a string.

One way to work around this is to parse the response string to a `JArray` and build your strongly-typed list one by one, handling parsing errors along the way:

```
var results = new List<SeatTest>();

var arr = JArray.Parse(response);
foreach (var obj in arr) {
    try {
        var seat = obj.ToObject<SeatTest>();
        results.Add(seat);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        // parsing error, inspect ex and obj.ToString(). log? ignore?
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @ToddMenier for your advice. I manage to put each json attribute in different file and load them from my desktop. I realize that I have a problem reading a string that contains HTML information on it. Once I commented that line I manage to read the entire thing at least using Json.Net. I'm going to open a new quation and accept this answer as the solution since the problem is not Flurl, but rather how to read HTML as a string withing the Json.

Comment: Just for the record, here is the new [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57265440/problem-with-json-deserialization-of-html-string-using-json-net) with the real issue.