# Problem with Json Deserialization of html string using Json.Net

Tags: c#, html, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I'm not an expert with json, actually I started last week working with it and I found myself having trouble trying to get map the following [Json](https://gis.cdc.gov/grasp/fluView6/GetFlu6AllDataP) into a class.

S far I have copy the data from the browser into different Json files (isolate data to see the problem) and I realize that the property **Config** mess the deserialization process. If I **(1)** grab the entire data and **(2)** put it into a file and **(3)** add the extension **.json** and then later **(4)** just erase the Config property, everything works like a charm. But I want to be able to deserialize the whole thing.

For reading the url I'm using **Flurl** to generate a string from the response as I mentioned in a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57223821/json-deserialization-is-not-working-with-flurl) using the `GetStringAsync()` and for generating the Classes I just paste the response from **Flurl** or **Postman** into a [Json2Csharp converter](https://www.site24x7.com/tools/json-to-csharp.html). Now for Deserialization I have try the following using Json.Net.

````
//Test 1
string cleanseStr = Regex.Unescape(FlurlResponse);
var myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(cleanseStr );

//Test 2
FlurlResponse= FlurlResponse.Replace("\\\\\\", "\\\\");            
FlurlResponse= FlurlResponse.Replace("\\\\", "\\");
var myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(FlurlResponse);```

//Test 3
FlurlResponse= FlurlResponse.Replace("\\\\\\", "\\\\");            
string cleanseStr = Regex.Unescape(FlurlResponse);
var myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(cleanseStr );
````

So far, I had no luck. I get **errors** at the **beginning** of the json or at the **end** saying that "cannot convert string into [MyModel]". I also took the response value from **Test1** and **Test2** (if I'm not istaken) and add it to [this](https://www.unserialize.me) unserializer using **"Json" to "Unserialized print_r"** as my settings and compare them to my deserialization by hand (before using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`) and I got the same result.

At the moment I'm stuck thinking ***what I'm missing in order to correctly deserialize the HTML string*** within the Json from the Config property. Probably someone that had face the same problem in the past can help me deserialize this or give any advice.

```
Error: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error converting value blah and 4millions characters later... "value":"<span fontWeight=\" to type TestingAPI.MyModel'. Path '', line 1, position 250 (for Test2) or 1950 (for Test1 and 3, 1950 means the end of the file).
```

### ConfigProperty.json, What really matter is the format and not the words for the string, I left all the symbols as the original property.

```
"{\"Config\":[{\"id\":1,\"description\":\"Title\",\"value\":\"blah, blah\"},{\"id\":2,\"description\":\"Dislcaimer\",\"value\":\"<span fontWeight=\\\"bold\\\"> blah- </span>\\r\\n<br/><br/>blah 101 bl.ah. <span fontWeight=\\\"bold\\\"> blah (blah) blah 101 blah\\r\\n blah blah (blah)</span> blah, blah,\\r\\n blah. blah.\\r\\n blah, blah. blah, blah\\r\\n blah.\\r\\n<br/><br/>blah, blah, blah, blah blah\\r\\n blah blah-ah blah. blah (bl-ah blah, bl-ah blah, bl-ah blah, and >blah)\\r\\n blah.\\r\\n<br/><br/>blah, blah\\r\\n blah. \\r\\n<br/><br/>blah:<a 
href=\\\"http://blah.blah.blah/blah/blah/blah.htm#blah\\\">http://blah.blah.blah/blah/blah/blah.htm#blah</a>\"}]}"
```

### EDIT

I solved my problem in a not very pleasant way, manual deserialization:

```
string cleanseStr= Regex.Unescape(FlurlResponseString);
cleanseStr= cleanseStr.Replace("\r\n", "");
cleanseStr= cleanseStr.Replace("\\\\\\", "\\\\");
cleanseStr= cleanseStr.Replace("=\"", "=\\\"");
cleanseStr= cleanseStr.Remove(0, 1);
cleanseStr= cleanseStr.Remove(scapedJson.Length - 1, 1);
MyModel _myModel= new MyModel();
JsonConvert.PopulateObject(cleanseStr, _myModel);
```

The correct way is proposed by @BrianRogers, thank you @BrianRogers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the real problem here is that the original JSON is *double-serialized*.  That is, it was serialized from an object to JSON and then that JSON string was serialized *again*, resulting in extra backslashes and quotes in the string.

So, to deserialize it, you need to do the reverse: deserialize the downloaded double-serialized JSON to a normal JSON string, then deserialize that string to an object.

I was able to do this successfully using the following code (Flurl.Http + Json.Net):

```
string json = await "https://gis.cdc.gov/grasp/fluView6/GetFlu6AllDataP".GetStringAsync();
json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(json);
MyModel model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(json);
```

With the following model classes:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public List<Group> Group { get; set; }
    public List<Season> Season { get; set; }
    public List<Age> Age { get; set; }
    public List<VirusType> VirusType { get; set; }
    public List<VirusData> VirusData { get; set; }
    public List<Config> Config { get; set; }
    public List<LastWeek> LastWeek { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class Season
{
    public int SeasonID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int StartWeek { get; set; }
    public int EndWeek { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public bool ShowLabType { get; set; }
}

public class Age
{
    public int AgeID { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Color_HexValue { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}

public class VirusType
{
    public int VirusID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public int StartMMWRID { get; set; }
    public int EndMMWRID { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public string ColorName { get; set; }
    public string Color_HexValue { get; set; }
    public int LabTypeID { get; set; }
    public int SortID { get; set; }
}

public class VirusData
{
    public int VisrusID { get; set; }
    public int AgeID { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public int MMWRID { get; set; }
    public int Seasonid { get; set; }
    public int PublishYearWeekID { get; set; }
    public string LoadDateTime { get; set; }
}

public class Config
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class LastWeek
{
    public int MMWRID { get; set; }
    public DateTime WeekEnd { get; set; }
    public int WeekNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime WeekStart { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string YearWeek { get; set; }
    public int SeasonID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I remember doing this but I did a mistake I did something like this

     var json1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(json);
     var json2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(json1); 
     MyModel model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(json2);

Because someone told me that was double serialize in my ignorant head I thought of the above lines which is equivalent to deserialization x3. Thanks for the clarification @BrianRogers